# iPhone: Picking a file from a location for uploading to server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file-upload

I'm making a client-server program for picking a file from a location on a Mac desktop and then copying it into a iPhone simulator. Then, it'll upload it to the server using the TCP protocol.

Can anyone please suggest how to do it or can suggest a site where I can learn about it. I got the following code on internet, will it perform the above required task?

```
if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath:source] )
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyPath:source toPath:destination handler:nil];

[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] performFileOperation:NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation source:foldername destination:@"" files:filenamesArray tag:&tag];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at ASIHTTPRequest: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Following is the piece of code I use ASIHTTPRequest to upload a file.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addPostValue:token forKey:@"token"];
[request setFile:recorderFilePath forKey:@"thefile"];
[request startSynchronous];
```

NOTE, the variable recorderFilePath is the path to a audio file, this is a file I created in app document directory, added following code to your header file, will help you to get your document directory.

```
#define DOCUMENTS_FOLDER [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]
```

Comment: @ dongsheng At the place of url can i put my server address.

Comment: Yes, the url in [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url] should be your server url.

Comment: Don't forget to read the documentation of ASIHTTPRequest, startSynchronous will block your thread and that's probably not what you want. So user startAsynchronous and a delegate.